# Ignoring space between empty/optional command arguments

Tags: macros, spacing

*(This may be a duplicate, but I could not find an answer among the pile of similar questions...)*

Suppose we have the following command:

```
% <month> <year> <month> <year>
\newcommand{\timeperiod}[4] {%
#1 #2 -- #3 #4%
}
```

As long as all arguments are provided, everything works fine. *But* were one to omit e.g. the second month argument (`#3`), an extra space would appear between the dash and the ending year:

```
June 2000 – July 2001
June 2000 –  2001
```

How could I suppress that extra space? Or better yet, how could I make LaTeX ignore any spacing between empty command arguments?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's see what happens:

```
\timeperiod{June}{2000}{July}{2001}
```

becomes

```
June•2000•--•July•2001
```

(where I use `•` to make spaces more visible). With

```
\timeperiod{June}{2000}{}{2001}
```

you get

```
June•2000•--••2001
```

Indeed consecutive spaces are reduced to one only when TeX is reading input and converting it to tokens; the definition text has already been tokenized, so those two spaces remain. You can avoid the double space by saying

```
\newcommand{\timeperiod}[4]{%
  #1 #2 -- #3\unskip\space#4%
}
```

If `#3` is empty, the `\unskip` will remove the space between `--` and the (empty) argument. If `#3` is not empty, `\unskip` will do nothing.

Comment: +1 Perfect! This does exactly what I want. I also appreciate the explanation...

Answer (score 9):

use

```
\newcommand\timeperiod[4] {#1 #2 -- \ifx\relax#3\relax\else#3~\fi#4}
```

Comment: +1 This does work, although it is a bit complex...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `xspace` package ([Insert a space after a command: {}, vs \ , vs \space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/362046/insert-a-space-after-a-command-vs-vs-space)):

```latex
\usepackage{xspace}

% <month> <year> <month> <year>
\newcommand{\timeperiod}[4] {%
#1\xspace#2\xspace--\xspace#3\xspace#4%
}
```

But do not forget about [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace)