# Insert a space after a command: {}, vs \ , vs \space

Tags: macros, best-practices

I'm used to insert a space after a command by using the `{}`, e.g. `\mycommand{} some other text`, in order to circumvent the space-gobbling of commands.

I'm wondering if it's best or what are the specific drawbacks or differences between the following:

`\mycommand{} some text`

`\mycommand\ some text`

`\mycommand\space some text`

is it a matter of habit or do the spaces and mechanics differ?

Thanks

Comment: See [Space after LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/) and all the linked duplicates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I prefer the `\myCommand{}` appraoch since there is no risk that I
>   create a false command by accident as with `\myCommand\` (e. g. when I
>   forget the space after `\` and LaTeX complains that the "command" is
>   unknown). I have never used `\space` before.

There is also a package called [`xspace`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xspace). One of the authors is the Stackexchange high reputation user [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle).

The `xspace` package provides a command called `\xspace` which will decide if a space is necessary or not. Here's an example taken from the manual:

**Command Definition**

```
\newcommand{\gb}{Great Britain\xspace}
```

**Use of Command**

```
\gb is a very nice place to live.\\
\gb, a small island off the coast of France.\\
\gb\footnote{The small island off the coast of France.}
is a very nice place to live.
```

**Output**

[image]

> So the benefit is, that you don't need to worry about your question
>   when you define **your own commands**.

### Related Questions

- [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091)
- [No space following macro without argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25820)
- [Problem with \newcommand, no space after calling new command in the compiled text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17872)
- [\newcommand and spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17730)
- [Usage of LaTeX macro \space (compared with \␣)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119717) (about the `\space` command)
- [What commands are there for horizontal spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74353) (also about the `\space` command)

Comment: Is there a good solution for macros with arguments? (to avoid `\gb{big}, I like it here` -> 'GB , I like it here'). Preferably w/o xspace package

Comment: @Dániel Somogyi Have a look at the csquotes package.